# How to use positioned Widget in Stack Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I want to get the screen like that(upper Image),
But when I try to make it ,I just get this screen (below Image),I don't know how to get upper screen .Please help me.
I think there is something wrong with my code.

This is my code.

> ```
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
>
> class SettingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
>   const SettingScreen({super.key});[![enter image description here][2]][2]
>
>   @override
>   State<SettingScreen> createState() => _SettingScreenState();
> }
>
> class _SettingScreenState extends State<SettingScreen> {
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Scaffold(
>       body: SafeArea(
>           child: Column(
>         children: [
>           Container(
>             width: double.infinity,
>             height: 100,
>             decoration: BoxDecoration(
>                 boxShadow: const [
>                   BoxShadow(
>                       color: Colors.black26,
>                       blurRadius: 90,
>                       offset: Offset(4, 9))
>                 ],
>                 gradient: LinearGradient(
>                     colors: [
>                       Color.fromARGB(255, 170, 148, 210),
>                       Color.fromARGB(255, 65, 160, 195),
>                       Color.fromARGB(255, 134, 174, 207),
>                       Color.fromARGB(255, 155, 187, 212),
>                     ],
>                     begin: Alignment.topLeft,
>                     end: Alignment.topRight,
>                     stops: [0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 1.4])),
>             child: Padding(
>               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
>               child: Row(children: [
>                 Text(
>                   "REL" + '\n' + "  ATE",
>                   style: TextStyle(
>                     color: Colors.white,
>                     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                     fontSize: 10,
>                     letterSpacing: 20,
>                   ),
>                 ),
>                 SizedBox(
>                   width: 130,
>                 ),
>                 Icon(
>                   Icons.skip_next_rounded,
>                   color: Colors.white,
>                   size: 50,
>                 ),
>               ]),
>             ),
>           ),
>           Stack(
>             children: [
>               Container(
>                 width: 300,
>                 height: 522,
>                 decoration:
>                     BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: const [
>                   BoxShadow(
>                     color: Colors.black,
>                     offset: Offset(1, 2),
>                     blurRadius: 50,
>                   )
>                 ]),
>               ),
>               Positioned(
>                 top: 10,
>                 right: 3,
>                 child: SizedBox(
>                   child: Container(
>                     // width: 500,
>                     child: Column(
>                       children: [
>                         Text(
>                           "SETTINGS",
>                           style: TextStyle(
>                               color: Colors.black,
>                               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                               fontSize: 30,
>                               letterSpacing: 20),
>                         ),
>                         Padding(
>                           padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 100, top: 10),
>                           child: Text(
>                             "ACCOUNT",
>                             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
>                           ),
>                         ),
>                         Divider(
>                           color: Colors.grey,
>                           thickness: 100,
>                           height: 20,
>                         )
>                       ],
>                     ),
>                   ),
>                 ),
>               )
>             ],
>           )
>         ],
>       )),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

But I get the second screen, and "S" is missing in Settings .Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Stack's clipBehavior, set it to

```
clipBehavior: Clip.none,
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you so much. It like a magic .Thank you so so much. It really worked